# Is it possible to enable rules in Rubocop only for new classes

Tags: rubocop

I would like to enable `ClassLength` rule on Rubocop but only for new classes such that we don't start getting alerts for all the legacy code. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can [ignore your legacy files](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#includingexcluding-files) in `.rubocop.yml`, either as a long list or as a few globs if you can isolate them into directories.

```
Metrics/ClassLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'one/file'
    - 'another/file'
    - 'some/dir/*'
```

If there are just a few really bad offenders but the rest are over the default (100 lines), you can [pick a higher threshold](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/v0.35.1/config/default.yml#L805-L807).

```
Metrics/ClassLength:
  max: 200
```

You can also add [annotations to disable cops](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#disabling-cops-within-source-code) in each of the files where you want to ignore `Metrics/ClassLength`:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
class SuperLongScaryThing
  # ...
end
# rubocop:enable Metrics/ClassLength
```

And of course, you can always do some refactoring!